# page are not redirect on same page when submit?

Tags: php, codeigniter, captcha

controller: test.php

```
<?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
    class Test extends CI_Controller 
    {
        function __construct() 
        {
            parent :: __construct();
            $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url', 'captcha'));
            $this->load->model('Fetch_data');
            $this->session->set_flashdata('');
        }
        public function login()
        {
            if($this->input->post('signup'))
            {
                $data  = array(
                                'firstname' => $this->input->post('fname'),
                                'lastname' => $this->input->post('lname'),
                                'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                                'phone' => $this->input->post('mobile'),
                                'city' => $this->input->post('city'),
                                'interest_field' => $this->input->post('interest_field'),
                                'password' => $this->input->post('password')
                              );


                $this->db->select('*');
                $this->db->from('students');
                $where = "email = '".$this->input->post('email')."'";
                $this->db->where($where);
                $query = $this->db->get();
                if ($query->num_rows() > 1)
                {
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('message', '<p style="color: red;font-weight: bold;">Email Id already exist. Please login with diffrent email id.</p>');
                }
                else
                {
                    $inputCaptcha = $this->input->post('captcha');
                    $sessCaptcha = $this->session->userdata('captchaCode');
                    if($inputCaptcha === $sessCaptcha)
                    {
                        return $this->db->insert('students',$data);
                        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', '<p style="color: #89c343;font-weight: bold;">Successfull.</p>');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', '<p style="color: red;font-weight: bold;">Captcha code was not match, please try again.</p>');
                    }
                }
            }
            $config = array(
                'img_path'      => 'resources/img/captcha_images/',
                'img_url'       => base_url().'resources/img/captcha_images/',
                'img_width'     => '200',
                'img_height'    => 40,
                'word_length'   => 8,
                'font_size'     => 16
            );
            $captcha = create_captcha($config);
            $this->session->unset_userdata('captchaCode');
            $this->session->set_userdata('captchaCode',$captcha['word']);
            $data['captchaImg'] = $captcha['image'];
            $this->load->view('login',$data);
        }
    }
```

view: login.php

```
<?php echo form_open(base_url('index.php/')."test/login");?>

    <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" placeholder="Your First Name" class="text-line"/>

    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" class="text-line"/>

    <input type="text" name="mobile" id="mobile" placeholder="Your Mobile" class="text-line"/>

    <p id="captImg"><?php echo $captchaImg; ?></p>
    <input type="text" name="captcha" value="" class="captcha" placeholder="Enter Image Inputs"/>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="refreshCaptcha" >Can't Read Please Refersh Image</a>
    <input type="submit" name="signup" id="signup" value="Sign Up" class="btn btn-warning"/>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

In this code I have create a form having captcha where captcha and email Id already exist are working perfectly but when I inserting value into students table. The form value are inserting into the database but the page are not redirect on login page. Now, I want that when click on submit button it will insert value into the table and display successfull message.

Thank You

Comment: `<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>">`   Why You Not try this ..

Answer (score 0):

> **View.login.php**

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>">

    <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" placeholder="Your First Name" class="text-line"/>

    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" class="text-line"/>

    <input type="text" name="mobile" id="mobile" placeholder="Your Mobile" class="text-line"/>

    <p id="captImg"><?php echo $captchaImg; ?></p>
    <input type="text" name="captcha" value="" class="captcha" placeholder="Enter Image Inputs"/>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="refreshCaptcha" >Can't Read Please Refersh Image</a>
    <input type="submit" name="signup" id="signup" value="Sign Up" class="btn btn-warning"/>

</form>
```

Comment: Nothing happen it showing blank page and inserting value into the database  @RishiKesh Kumar

Comment: @omkara you want to redirect to `login.php` page ??

Comment: will you please see controller I think problem was there ? I am trying redirect but it will not working @RishiKesh Kumar

Comment: In my controller I return insert query that's why page are not redirect.

Comment: but it will generate one more issue i.e. when I insert form value it display successfull msg when refresh page msg will still show again refresh page then msg hide. why

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148110/discussion-between-rishikesh-kumar-and-omkara).

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
redirect('controllerName/function_name_where_you_want_to_redirect');
```

It would be better if you create a separate index() function inside controller containing only

```
$this->load->view('view_name');
```

Then redirect to that function as already mentioned.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

To redirect on the same page after submitting the form you don't need to pass any parameter in the **form_open()** function.